# Which openiddict sample is good to read for WebAPI authorization and external React authentication and authorization?

Tags: openiddict

Which openiddict server sample is good to try and to customize for WebAPI authorization and external React authentication and authorization?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the Velusia and Balosar samples:

- https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/Velusia
- https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/Balosar

Comment: Are there any react SPA specific examples, similar to the Microsoft React SPA template but with openiddict and not ID4?